# CSV as datasource for javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, datasource

I finally made it through scraping some data out to csv, sending it to get geo encoded and then dumped back out to a new csv with the new columns.. after all that what I can't figure out is how to use some javascript to get the csv data in to an array or object on the page.. can anyone point me in a fairly simply direction?

Comment: I spent forever looking at this example, and honestly I know nothing about javascript.. how does CSV get a value in that example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use a [csv to json converter](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm)

2) Copy and paste the generated json into a script tag in your html

```
<script type='text/javascript>
   window.data = [
      // paste here
   ];
</script>
```

3) Use the `window.data` variable in your scripts.

4) Profit.

This is *really* simple, but your question didn't specify the need for anything more robust. No dependencies. Up and running fast.

Comment: thanks for providing some sort of answer instead of just blowing me off..  I went ahead and used the json converter and am loading it in using $.getJSON('auction.json');

Comment: Yeah I disagree with the close. You weren't asking to parse the CSV in javascript necessarily. You wanted a strategy for loading it.